# Spring Boot integration into Apache NIFI

Tags: spring-boot, apache-nifi

I'm trying to make a process in Nifi that will look like this => read csv, convert to json and write it to db, but I have to use dao classes from my spring boot project instead of `PutDatabaseRecord`.

I've tried using `SpringContextProcessor` (made spring project that had spring boot project as a dependency), but Nifi seems not to catch up configuration yml file and can't create connection to db.

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

There are already processors that can convert between CSV and JSON, such as ConvertRecord. So I would suggest writing a custom processor that expects JSON and uses your spring-boot DAO classes.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ConvertRecord and I'm further connecting it to SpringContextProcessor. I also tried with custom processor, as you suggested, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Ok so far you haven't shown any error, people would need to see an error from nifi-app.log to better help you